# My NMOS inverter is showing negative spikes in the LTspice simulation

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

[image]

The red line is the input and the green line is the NMOS Output.
[image]

I am doing a 10ms transient analysis at the output, but if the capacitance is 0 then I am getting a negative spike when the input is on falling edge. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am getting a negative spike when the input is on falling edge. Why
> is this?*

In a MOSFET there is capacitance between gate and drain so, when the gate voltage falls to zero rapidly, the effect it has is to capacitively couple energy through to the drain and start to forward bias the bulk diode in most MOSFETs hence, it gets limited to about -0.7 volts (or thereabouts).

In short: capacitive coupling from gate to drain.

Comment: Ahh, I see, Thanks for your time!

Comment: how do I calculate the value of C1 so I could attain the tightest rising and falling time while removing the voltage spikes?

Comment: You can't remove them even if you increased C1 a lot. So, ask yourself what problem are you trying to solve or, what will happen if you leave the negative spikes intact?

Comment: I was trying out different C1 values and it seems to go away after that? Doesn't the charge capacitor discharge hence removing the negative spike? But don't know how that work in a positive spike situation during the input rising edge, hence the spike will be at the beginning edge of the falling strike. Do the negative spikes effect the driven circuit?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the negative spike affecting what follows the circuit. You won't get a problem on the rising edge on the gate because the MOSFET turns on. Think about what I said earlier - why should a small negative voltage cause you a problem?

Comment: wouldn't it reverse bias the a diode or a transistor if connected to the output?

Comment: It might but is this a problem? If the output were fed to a sensitive input then it could do damage but I'm not going to speculate.

Comment: honestly the spikes don't bother me, I just wanted to know if there is a way to get rid of it? But I haven't tried this out practically and I don't know if the negative spike can kill a the MOS which it shouldn't because the MOS in question is rated for  ±20V max

Comment: It will be clamped by the internal body diode so I wouldn't worry about it.